# What are the limitation using before unload event?

Tags: javascript, browser

What is and what is not possible to do inside the `beforeunload` callback ?

Is it possible to open an XHR/fetch and send data to the server ?
 If no, is it possible to just send data, without any success callback blocking ?

Is it possible to change the location of the page with `window.location`? 
How long does the function continue to execute?

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (event) {
    // code
});
```

Comment: If the function is synchronous, it should always be executed till the end.

Comment: What research have you done?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can put anything you want inside of a "beforeunload" callback, you're just not guaranteed it will execute unless you use synchronous/blocking code.

Here's a blocking sleep function I'll use for demonstration purposes:

```
function sleep(delay) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  while (new Date().getTime() < start + delay);
}
```

Any synchronous, blocking code is guaranteed to execute to completion:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (event) {
  console.log("Blocking for 1 second...");
  sleep(1000);
  console.log("Done!!");
});
```

Any async code (i.e. code with callbacks) like the code below will be queued on the event loop, but it may or may not finish executing depending on when your browser completes the "unload" action (e.g. close window, refresh page.) The time here really depends on your computer's performance.  On my computer, for example, a timeout of 10ms with log statement still executes because my browser hasn't had time to refresh/close the page.

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (event) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("Timeout finished!"); // Odds are this will finish
  }, 10);
  console.log("Done!!");
});
```

A timeout of 100ms, however, is never executed:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (event) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("Timeout finished!");
  }, 100);
  console.log("Done!!");
});
```

The only way to guarantee your function will run to completion is to make sure you're writing synchronous code that blocks the event loop as in the first example.

Comment: Question, would adding a `while(!asyncCompleted);` blocker work?

Comment: Nope. The while loop will block the async event from ever completing, so you'll be trapped in an infinite loop.

Comment: Interesting. What if you create a WebWorker?

Comment: Is it possible to send an XHR and sending data to the server ? Is it possible to change the location of the page ?

Comment: If a page fires its unload event, it means the user wants to go somewhere else. Why you would interfere with that?? I don't know. I mean, can you imagine mom walking in the room.... cmd + q, cmd + q, cmd + q ... mother disowns son.

Comment: Do `event.preventDefault()` to prevent this from happening.

Comment: @WalleCyril It's currently possible to send a synchronous XMLHttpRequest  if you force it to be synchronous, but this is deprecated in some browsers. Also, you can't change the page location since the location change gets queued as an async event in most browsers (i.e. the browser doesn't transition until a connection is established.)

Comment: @RyanWheale The main use case for this is detecting when the user has filled in a form but not submitted it, or done some other action without saving, and we're trying to help.

Comment: So in your first example, if I wanted to write code that's guaranteed to run, where would I put it? I see that you've made a sleep function which blocks the event loop, but which console.log is guaranteed to run? Where would you put something guaranteed to complete, such as submitting a GET request?

Comment: This effectively mean that you cannot be sure to save something to indexedDB before exiting. Is there any update about this?

Comment: Is this behavior documented somewhere?

Comment: What if we await the async function? Something like `await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));`

Answer (score 10):

To help some of the people in the comments on the first answer, check out this functionality to make an XHR request during the unload event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon

Comment: Excellent __________!

Comment: The docs says otherwise: 
`It’s intended to be used in combination with the visibilitychange event (but not with the unload and beforeunload events).`