# JQuery 'beforeunload' event doesn't console.log the response from $.post to mail() in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, email, onbeforeunload

I've been trying to send an email whenever a user is trying to quit the page, i have used the `beforeunload` event in jQuery.

**jQuery Code:**

```
 $(window).on("beforeunload", function(e) {
     console.log('posting');
     $.post("file.php", {
             d: logData,
             s: 'New User Activity',
             t: 'example@gmail.com',
             r: 'From: info@address.com\r\n',
      },
      function(data, status) {
        console.log(data);
      );
 });
```

This code always logs successfully the response from `file.php` unless i'm using the mail() function, btw it only doesn't `console.log` whatever after the mail() function.

## file.php contents:

```
<?php
$fo = fopen("file.txt","a");
fwrite($fo,"Contents:\n".$_POST['d']."\nSubject: ".$_POST['s']."\nTo:".$_POST['t']);
fclose($fo); // THIS WORKS SUCCESSFULLY

mail("example@domain.com","Subject","Msg"); //I changed this to static values so i check if the problem
//is coming from the POST, but still no success

echo "fine"; //THIS DOESN'T SHOW UP IN THE CONSOLE
?>
```

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42914045/965834). You may want to use a synchronous request in your case (see `async: false` in jQuery's docs).

Comment: Thank you @Jeto that was the solution, please write your comment in the answer box so i can approve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41909365/what-are-the-limitation-using-before-unload-event/42914045#42914045).

Basically, anything asynchronous in the `beforeunload` might not execute, depending on when your browser actually unloads the page.

Try using a synchronous request in your case, by passing `async: false` to your call ([docs here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)).