# onDelete is not working after confirm alert in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The confirm alert shows before the users are going to move from the page in React. If they respond YES, I want to run `onDelete()`. The below code runs `onDelete()` if they respond NO also.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.setupBeforeUnloadListener();
}

setupBeforeUnloadListener() {
  window.addEventListener("beforeunload", (event) => {
    event.returnValue = `Are you sure you want to leave?`;
    this.onDelete();
  })
}
```

How can I run `onDelete()` only if the users respond YES in confirm alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the `unload` event together with `beforeunload`. `beforeunload` will give the user the chance to cancel the unload, and the `unload` event will be triggered if the user does not cancel the unload.

Note that most browsers ignore any custom prompt string
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload#Browser_compatibility

> When this event returns (or sets the returnValue property to) a value other than null or undefined, the user will be prompted to confirm the page unload. In older browsers, the return value of the event is displayed in this dialog. Starting with Firefox 44, Chrome 51, Opera 38, and Safari 9.1, a generic string not under the control of the webpage will be shown instead of the returned string. For example:
>
> Firefox displays the string, "This page is asking you to confirm that
>   you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved." (see bug
>   588292). Chrome displays the string, "Do you want to leave this site?
>   Changes you made may not be saved." (see Chrome Platform Status).

Also, if your onDelete() function does anything asynchronous it's not guaranteed to complete. See this discussion for more info: [What are the limitation using before unload event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41909365/what-are-the-limitation-using-before-unload-event)

Comment: Thanks I've got it! And completely it has been solved!