# Angular Material dialog not closing after dialog.close() function

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I'm struggling with this problem for a while, so maybe someone will be able to help.

In my Angular project I have a dialog in my login component which opens a new popup window.
After successful login this window is closing and following function is triggered:

```
loginWindow.onbeforeunload = (e) => { 
  this.dialogRef.close()
}
```

And here comes the problem because dialog is still opened but I just need to click anything on the screen( even the dialog itself ) and dialog disappears.

I tried to first set focus on this window and then trigger close function but effect is still the same. Using closeAll() gives similar result.

Thanks for any help:)

EDIT:

Here's my component code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MatDialogConfig } from '@angular/material/dialog';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login-page',
  templateUrl: './login-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login-page.component.scss']
})
export class LoginPageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<LoginPageComponent>
  ) { }

  //some other functions

  close() {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

  newWindow() {
    const loginWindow = window.open(popupWindowUrl,"_blank","height=200,width=400,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no");
    loginWindow.onbeforeunload = (e) => { 
      this.dialogRef.close();
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you share your html code??

Comment: At this moment everything I have in dialog html code is button to open popup window.

Comment: @MichałB: Did you ever get this resolved? I have the same issue: sometimes when this.dialogRef.close() is called, the dialog remains on screen even though I can tell that the associated afterClosed event did fire.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share some code ?

How to you close your dialog ?
Are you keeping a ref to your dialog ? If so can you close it with dialogRef.close();

Edit:
Maybe this can help you out - [What are the limitation using before unload event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41909365/what-are-the-limitation-using-before-unload-event/42914045#42914045)

Try wrap your code inside a timeout

Comment: I add some code in my question. I'm also using antoher dialogs and all works just fine except this one with popup window.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't help. I think it might have something to do with parent window losing focus. Even when I was clicking right mouse button anywhere, this dialog disappears.